# Need help on formatting proper SQL query based on specific criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current table `sandbox`:

```
| id | parent_id | title | text |
|----|-----------|-------|------|
| 1  | 11        | some  | text |
| 2  | 11        | some  | text |
| 3  | 11        | some  | text |
| 4  | 11        | some  | text |
| 5  | 11        | some  | text |
| 6  | 14        | some  | text |
| 7  | 14        | some  | text |
| 8  | 19        | some  | text |
| 9  | 19        | some  | text |
```

What I want to achieve is to leave N most recent rows based on particular parent_id, while leaving other rows with different parent_ids intact.

For example, a table with 3 most recent parent_id = 11, should look like this:

```
| id | parent_id | title | text |
|----|-----------|-------|------|
| 3  | 11        | some  | text |
| 4  | 11        | some  | text |
| 5  | 11        | some  | text |
| 6  | 14        | some  | text |
| 7  | 14        | some  | text |
| 8  | 19        | some  | text |
| 9  | 19        | some  | text |
```

I already tried this:

```
DELETE FROM `sandbox`
WHERE id <= (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM `sandbox`
    WHERE parent_id = 11
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3 <-- keep this many records
  ) foo
)
```

But then I loose other rows, getting table like this:

```
| id | parent_id | title | text |
|----|-----------|-------|------|
| 3  | 11        | some  | text |
| 4  | 11        | some  | text |
| 5  | 11        | some  | text |
```

Any help on proper SQL query would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `parent_id = 11` in the WHERE clause and use NOT IN to avoid deleting the 3 more recent rows:

```
DELETE FROM `sandbox`
WHERE parent_id = 11
AND id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM `sandbox`
    WHERE parent_id = 11
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ) foo
)
```